# Simple query rephrasing for optimization

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgresql-9.4, explain

The following query:

```
select exists(select id 
              from   avl_adc_equipo cfg 
              where  cfg.imei=354676052451142 
              and    cfg.adc=2)
```

Executes pretty fast, but as it gets called thousands of times using variations in `imei` and `adc` columns, it adds quite a high number of seconds.

It's `explain analyze verbose` output is:

```
Result  (cost=4.29..4.30 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: $0
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Only Scan using pk_avl_adc_equipo on public.avl_adc_equipo cfg  (cost=0.28..4.29 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ((cfg.imei = 354676052451142::bigint) AND (cfg.adc = 2))
          Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.060 ms
Execution time: 0.027 ms
```

So, it's basically already using the table's PK for performance, but I guess the exists part is not the better approach.

Table schema:

[image: Table Schema]

```
Indexes:
    "pk_avl_adc_equipo" PRIMARY KEY, btree (imei, adc)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_avl_adc_nombre__avl_adc_equipo" FOREIGN KEY (id_adcnom) REFERENCES avl_adc_nombre(id_adcnom) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Any ideas? Anything else should I provide?

Comment: Please add your table schema.

Comment: @McNets schema and indexes added!

Comment: Seeing that twice as much time is spent in the planning stage as is in the execution stage, you may well consider using a parameterized query.

Comment: I suppose you're selecting something else if this record exists, is this correct?